# Trouble Mapping DeviceIoControl Call Return Value Structs from C to C#

Tags: c#, c, winapi

I am modifying some code that queries the device tree and reports on the capabilities of the devices, specifically the USB ports and their speeds. I was getting back the _USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX object from the DeviceIoControl call but it inaccurately reports USB 3.0 as High Speed. Further research revealed that I need to get the _USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2 struct from the DeviceIoControl to accommodate USB 3.0. I am trying to map the new struct into C# from C and am a little confused on how to handle the two C unions that are present as members of the new(ish) _USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2 struct.

I did C in college oh, say, close to 20 years ago. The bulk of my career has been in Powerbuilder (don't laugh it was long ago), Java (don't laugh it was long ago) but mainly C#. Can any C gurus help me map these structs with unions into C# structs and possibly give me a clue as to how to marshal them across? Notice I have mapped the _USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2 but don't really know what to do with the _USB_PROTOCOLS and the _USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2_FLAGS structs. It would be nice to map the _USB_PROTOCOLS struct into a C# Flags enum so I could use bitwise and's and or's too.

The code below shows the C typedef commented out and my corresponding structs in C# (uncommented and... well, unfinished :( ). Thank you all in advance!

```
//typedef struct _USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2
    //{
    //    ULONG ConnectionIndex;
    //    ULONG Length;
    //    USB_PROTOCOLS SupportedUsbProtocols;
    //    USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2_FLAGS Flags;
    //}
    //USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2, *PUSB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2;

    struct USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2
    {
        public int ConnectionIndex;
        public int Length;
        public USB_PROTOCOLS SupportedUsbProtocols;
        public USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2_FLAGS Flags;
    }

    //typedef union _USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2_FLAGS {
    //  ULONG ul;
    //        struct {
    //    ULONG DeviceIsOperatingAtSuperSpeedOrHigher  :1;
    //        ULONG DeviceIsSuperSpeedCapableOrHigher  :1;
    //        ULONG ReservedMBZ  :30;
    //    };
    //}
    //USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2_FLAGS, * PUSB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2_FLAGS;
    struct USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2_FLAGS
    {

    }

    //typedef union _USB_PROTOCOLS {
    //  ULONG ul;
    //        struct {
    //        ULONG Usb110  :1;
    //        ULONG Usb200  :1;
    //        ULONG Usb300  :1;
    //        ULONG ReservedMBZ  :29;
    //    };
    //}
    //USB_PROTOCOLS, * PUSB_PROTOCOLS;
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    struct USB_PROTOCOLS
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`USB_PROTOCOLS` is a union struct, which is just wrapping a 32bit integer, where bit 0 is Usb110, bit 1 is Usb200, and bit 2 is Usb300. Define it like this:

```
public struct USB_PROTOCOLS
{
    UInt32 protocols;

    public bool Usb110 { get { return (this.protocols & 0x01) == 0x01; } }
    public bool Usb200 { get { return (this.protocols & 0x02) == 0x02; } }
    public bool Usb300 { get { return (this.protocols & 0x04) == 0x04; } }

}
```

The story for `USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2_FLAGS` is much the same, but for completeness:

```
public struct USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2_FLAGS
{
    UInt32 flags;

    public bool DeviceIsOperatingAtSuperSpeedOrHigher 
    { 
        get { return (this.flags & 0x01) == 0x01; } 
    }
    public bool DeviceIsSuperSpeedCapableOrHigher
    {
        get { return (this.flags & 0x02) == 0x02; }
    }
}
```

Alternately you could define both of these as enums, with the `Flags` attribute.

```
[Flags]
public enum USB_PROTOCOLS : uint
{
    Usb110 = 0x01,
    Usb200 = 0x02,
    Usb300 = 0x04,
}

[Flags]
public enum USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2_FLAGS : uint // nice short type name
{
    DeviceIsOperatingAtSuperSpeedOrHigher = 0x01,
    DeviceIsSuperSpeedCapableOrHigher = 0x02,
}
```

Or because three options are better than two, you could also change the first structure's definition to:

```
struct USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2
{
    public int ConnectionIndex;
    public int Length;
    public uint SupportedUsbProtocols;
    public uint Flags;
}
```

and do the bit manipulations yourself.

How did I do this? I opened up a C++ console application in Visual Studio, and wrote the following, then stepped through it in the debugger:

```
#include <usbioctl.h>

int size = sizeof(USB_PROTOCOLS); // size = 4
USB_PROTOCOLS proto = { 0 }; 
proto.Usb110 = 1;
unsigned int val = *((unsigned int*)(&proto)); // val = 1
proto.Usb110 = 0;
proto.Usb200 = 1;
val = *((unsigned int*)(&proto)); // val = 2
proto.Usb200 = 0;
proto.Usb300 = 1;
val = *((unsigned int*)(&proto)); // val = 4

size = sizeof(USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2_FLAGS); // size = 4
USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2_FLAGS flags = { 0 };
flags.DeviceIsOperatingAtSuperSpeedOrHigher = 1;
val = *((unsigned int*)(&flags)); // val = 1
flags.DeviceIsOperatingAtSuperSpeedOrHigher = 0;
flags.DeviceIsSuperSpeedCapableOrHigher = 1;
val = *((unsigned int*)(&flags)); // val = 2
```